# Addition/Subtraction of char and specifiers in printf statement in C

Tags: c

I've just started learning C, previously my experience with coding was mostly with Python. One thing that is confusing me the most is how individual characters can be added/subtracted, and how the printf statement works, especially regarding the format specifiers.

For example, in the code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char c1, c2;
  c1 = 'A' + '8' - '4';
  c2 = 'A' + '8' - '5';
  printf("%c, %d\n",c1,c2);
  return 0;
}
```

which returns E, 68.

There is an addition done on c1 and subtraction done on c2. What exactly is happening here? In addition, in the printf statement, we can see that the 2nd specifier in the format string is specified as %d, which represents a decimal integer. However, the relevant argument c2 is a char, and prints out 68 instead. What is happening here as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In C `char` is just an ordinary numerical type, so you can add and subtract accordingly. `'4'` is, on an ASCII-based system, 52. The only time "characters" exist is when it comes to displaying them, and that's the job of your terminal or GUI, not C.

Comment: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) holds the key...

Comment: You should do some experimenting, e.g. `for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) printf("%2d %c\n", c, c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tadman mentioned a `char` in C is just a numerical value.

So c1 boils down to 'A' (=65) + '8' (=56) - '4' (=52) = 69
and c2 boils down to 'A' (=65) + '8' (=56) - '5' (=53) = 68

the format specifiers in the `printf` statement just changes how these numerical values are printed.